# VSTS Analytics request blocked due to exceeding usage of resource AnalyticsBlockingResource

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

I have a PowerBI mashup that performs 4 queries against different VSTS projects on our tenant via the VSTS Analytics module. I have setup each query as a specific analytics views. Each view returns < 200 records and are simple "Get Story Backlog items" for a single team for today only.

I am frequently getting a message like the following:

> An error occurred in the ‘DS BI WorkItems’ query. Error: Request was
>   blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'AnalyticsBlockingResource'
>   in namespace 'User'. For more information on why your request was
>   blocked, see the topic "Rate limits" on the Microsoft Web site
>   (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=823950). Details:
>       DataSourceKind=Visual Studio Team Services
>       ActivityId=a6ac93f3-549c-4eb0-b64e-2b38e18ae7ee
>       Url=https://vrmobility.analytics.visualstudio.com/_odata/v2.0-preview/WorkItems?$filter=((ProjectSK%20eq%208e25983d-a154-4b53-915f-1394b34e5338)%20and%20((ProjectSK%20eq%208e25983d-a154-4b53-915f-1394b34e5338%20and%20Teams/any(t:t/TeamSK%20eq%2019afa381-35ca-47db-9060-51baa5d0485e))))%20and%20Processes/any(b:(b/BacklogName%20eq%20'Stories')%20and%20((b/ProjectSK%20eq%208e25983d-a154-4b53-915f-1394b34e5338%20and%20(b/TeamSK%20eq%2019afa381-35ca-47db-9060-51baa5d0485e))))&$select=LeadTimeDays,CycleTimeDays,CompletedDate,StateCategory,ParentWorkItemId,ActivatedDate,Activity,VRAgile_ActualCompletionIteration,VRAgile_ActualUatIteration,BusinessValue,VRAgile_ChangeAreaOwnerTeam,ChangedDate,ClosedDate,CompletedWork,VRAgile_CompletionTargetConfidence,CreatedDate,FinishDate,FoundIn,WorkItemId,VRAgile_IncludedinVersion,IntegrationBuild,OriginalEstimate,VRAgile_PlannedCompletionIteration,VRAgile_PlannedUATIteration,Priority,Reason,VRAgile_ReleaseQuality,RemainingWork,vrmobility_VRAgile_RequestedBy,VRAgile_RequestedDept,R...
>       error=Record

I have checked the page and looked at the Usage page on our VSTS tenant but during these times my user is not indicated as blocked and VSTS user interface works normally.

The issue goes away after a few minutes but it will then return after a couple of changes made in PowerBI (like adding a new column, changing data type etc) because this automatically refreshes all 4 queries again and this seems to trigger this unacceptable usage.

It is really frustrating as I can't continue working on the report and have to go and do something else for 5 minutes really impacting my flow.

Any ideas on cause, solution/workarounds? It feels to me like an overly sensitive VSTS limit on the VSTS Analytic service

Comment: Seems your issue could not reproduce stably. According to your description, that things are working for you again after the fail. The issue should more related to PowerBI and not related to VSTS.

Comment: I don't agree that this is more related to PowerBI and not VSTS. The error is coming from the VSTS REST service, so the solution is likely to be there? The information in the error from VSTS is not helpful as my user is not blocked or degraded in the way that the link on the message suggests and my queries are so small that for them to trigger a unacceptable usage seems ridiculous. Happy to add a PowerBI tag as well as vsts but definitely needs vsts tag there. I will clarify the reproducibility as I can reproduce reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps Services limits the resources individuals can consume and the number of requests they can make to certain commands. When these limits are exceeded, subsequent requests may be either delayed or blocked.

See the below link...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops